# Implementing MATLAB's "/" operator aka. mrdivide in C++ Eigen Library

Tags: c++, matlab, linear-algebra, eigen

I'm looking for a way to use the MATALB syntax `x = B / A;` in Eigen.

I know that one can extend the Matrix class in Eigen by defining the `EIGEN_MATRIXBASE_PLUGIN` variable (see [Eigen::Documentation](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicCustomizingEigen.html)).

And now my question is: How do I do this? And more important, how do I do this **efficiently**?

Edit:
As mentioned in the comments, I got this piece of code now:

```
const Matrix operator/ (const Matrix& other) const
{
    return ((other.transpose()).fullPivHouseholderQr().solve(this->transpose())).transpose();
}
```

This works for `x = B / A;` if both varaibles are of the type `Eigen::Matrix`, but if I got something like `Eigen::Matrix / double` there is no matching operator anymore. Since this is not that easy to implement correctly in Eigen, I will put that on hold for now.

Maybe someone with experience in extending Eigen classes can help with that...

Comment: Matlab has many nice features, toolboxes and functions but only few are REALLY REALLY amazing. `mldivide` is one of these AMAZING features. It covers so many scenarios (sparse/full/complex/over determined...) in an extremely efficient way. So why on earth would you like to give it up?

Comment: note that the two operators are related by `B/A = (A'\B')'`, so you can solve the above using the regular [Eigen solvers](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/group__TutorialLinearAlgebra.html) by just doing additional matrix transposes

Comment: Ok, thanks to @Amro, I now got `const MatrixBase<Derived> operator/ (const MatrixBase<Derived>& other) const
{
    return ((other.transpose()).fullPivHouseholderQr().solve(this->transpose())).transpose();
}` in my addon-file. To extend the MatrixBase class. But It doesn't work. I got the following error: conversion from `const Eigen::Transpose<const Eigen::ReturnByValue<Eigen::internal::solve_retval_base<Eigen::FullPivHouseholderQR<Eigen::Matrix<double,3,3,1,3,3>>, Eigen::Transpose<const Eigen::Matrix<double,3,3,0,3,3>>>>>' to non-scalar type `const Eigen::MatrixBase<[...]>' requested|

Comment: @NikolausAmmann: I dont have experience with extending Eigen, I was just answering from a linear-algebra point of view. As is often with C++ templates, errors messages are notoriously difficult to decipher :) Perhaps you should edit your question and post the code properly formatted, it will make it easier to read...

Comment: @NikolausAmmann: untested but what if you add another overloaded version specifically for the `Eigen::Matrix / double` case where you perform regular element-wise division? that is `const Matrix operator/(const double &x) const`.. Although I think you risk getting ambiguous overloading errors from the compiler if implicit conversion of `double->Matrix` is allowed in the constructor of `Matrix`?